# JavaScript Regexp to remove escaped backslashes and quotation marks in JSON

Tags: javascript, html, regex, json, escaping

According to what I've read ( [this article](http://www.thorntech.com/2012/07/4-things-you-must-do-when-putting-html-in-json/) for instance) you need to escape `\` and `"` when sending HTML as JSON.

I wanted to use `unescape()`, but it is deprecated since JS 1.5.

"*Use decodeURI() or decodeURIComponent() instead*", w3schools suggests. But `decodeURI()` or `decodeURIComponent()` do not escape `\` and `"`.

The response I'm getting looks something like:

```
"html": {
    "searchresult": "<div class=\\\"item\\\">\n\t\t\t<article class=\\\"unit\\\">\n\t\t\t\t<a href=\\\"page2.html\\\">Link<\\/a>\n\n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t<\\/article>\n\t\t<\\/div>"
}
```

I am then saving the following as `var markup`:

```
return $('<textarea/>').html( response ).val();
```

and am finally left with this semi working html

```
<div class=\"item\"> <article class=\"unit\"> <a href=\"page2.html\">Link<\/a> <\/article> <\/div>
```

I now need to remove all `\` before `"`, and `/\` for it work. Guess removing the whitespace in between the tags could be a bonus to.

I have tried the following to remove `\"`, which works great.

```
markup.replace('\\"', '"');
```

But I can't figure out how to also remove the `/\` (plus .replace(blah).replace(blah) doesn't feel right).
[This article](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/backslashinregularexpressions.htm) gave me a hint, but I still feel quite lost in the magic world of Regexp.

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: Don't do that.  You should use a JSON seralizer.

Comment: looks like a duplicate to me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't said where your data is coming from, but I'm going to assume at some point you have a valid HTML string (which apparently contains newlines and tabs), and apparently you're trying to make that the `searchresult` property of an `html` object inside an object, in JSON. Here's how you do that:

```
var json = JSON.stringify({html: yourString});
```

Example:

```js
var yourString =
    '<div class="item">\n\t\t\t<article class="unit">\n\t\t\t\t<a href="page2.html">Link</a>\n\n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t</article>\n\t\t</div>';
var json = JSON.stringify({html: yourString});
snippet.log("The JSON:");
snippet.log(json);
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Comment: First the json was sent as raw html, picked up from the page: `{html: "<div class='item'> <article class='unit'>"}; ` then we read that \ and " should be escaped, as mentioned in the article I've linked to. So now we are escaping \ and " manually.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick response! But I don't see that the output is valid HTML? Should I just not worry about escaping \ and " instead as this article suggests? http://www.thorntech.com/2012/07/4-things-you-must-do-when-putting-html-in-json/

Comment: @patad: You don't manually escape them; instead, you use a proper serializer. The result above is valid JSON that, when deserialized, provides an object with a property called `searchresult` whose value is a string containing valid HTML.

Comment: @Crowder: I have updated my question to clarify what I meant.  Could you please re-read it to see if your answer needs any update? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @patad: It's not a good idea to completely change your question like that. Instead, change it back and post a new question.

Comment: I see, sorry about that. However I can't find a way to revert it as there is no 'rollback' link and nothing happens when switching revision. If anyone knows how, please feel free to do so.

Comment: @patad: If you click the "edited XX minutes ago" link, that lists revisions, and there's a "rollback" link next to earlier ones. I've done it for you.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to change \"  to " over and entire string.

```
markup.toString().replace(/\\"/g,'"');
```

Comment: `  'asdfasdf\"sdfasdfasfsa\"asdfasdf'.replace(/\\"/g,'"'); `  returns  ` asdfasdf\"sdfasdfasfsa\"asdfasdf"  `  so all ` \" ` are not getting replaced.